# What are the implications of nested "su" command calls in a shell?

Tags: bash, root, exit, su

When I open a windows shell and write *su* to be a root user, I notice that I can write *su* again, and again, and again...  If I write *exit* then this lead me to the previous "*su* instance" (?), and I have to write as many *exit* as *su* I wrote.  What are the implications of this multiple "instances" and are there any advantages of this behaviuor?

Answer (score 4):

Within the Unix programming model, there is no way for a user process to gain the privileges of root or another user.

This means that it's not possible to write a version of `su` that simply turns your current shell into a root shell. Instead, you have to get root access by running a suid executable, and that necessarily creates a new instance.

There's no specific advantage, it just happens to be the only way to implement `su` in traditional Unix.

You can choose to use `exec su` instead of `su` to replace your current shell with the new instance. This means that `exit` in the root shell will simply log you out.

However, I would recommend just going with it. If you exit `vim` or `nano`, you expect to go back to your original shell. If you exit `ssh`, you expect to go back to your original shell. Don't try to make `su` an exception.

Comment: Could be said that _exec su_ opens a paralell shell instead a child one? What could be this useful for?

Comment: `exec su` just *replaces* the current shell with a new process.

Answer (score 1):

Each time you run the `su` command a new shell opens inside the current shell.

To exit a shell you run `exit`.

Answer (score 0):

When you execute su, you are going to create a subprocess (child process) of the parent shell. If you run bash (or zsh) in a shell, the meaning it's the same.

If you want to know the level of your current subshell just run `echo $SHLVL`.

Simply, when you run su multiple times, you are creating a family of process.